# String Array Search input

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a list of names from a text file: MARY, PATRICIA, LINDA, BARBARA, ELIZABETH, JENNIFER, MARIA that I put into a String Array. I want to be able to search the array, but I am having problems. I'd like to have it sorted using a quicksort algorithm, and to search using the Binary search, but I'm trying to get something simple to work. If I searched "MARY" the result would be "MARY is not it"

```
public class NameSearch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FileReader woMen = new FileReader("names.txt");

    String[] womenArray;
    womenArray = new String[64];

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(woMen);
    String line = null;

        for (int j=0;j<womenArray.length;j++)
        {
            womenArray[j] = reader.readLine();
        }

    reader.close();

    int x = 0, y =0;


    System.out.println("Name?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    for(int i=0;i<womenArray.length;i++) {
        if (input == womenArray[i]) {
            System.out.println("Found! "+input);
        }
        System.out.println(womenArray[i]+" is not it");
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in `if` statement. To match strings, you use `.equals` method like this:

```
System.out.println("Name?");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = keyboard.nextLine();

for(int i=0;i<womenArray.length;i++) {
    if (womenArray[i].equals(input)) {
        System.out.println("Found! "+input);
    }
}
```

And to sort the array, you use Array's sort method:

```
Arrays.sort(womenArray);
```

[Read about Arrays.sort(Object[] a) here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Also, you can use Arrays's built in binarySearch method. Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)

In your code, that would look like this:

```
int location = Arrays.binarySearch(womenArray, input)
```

if `location` is a negative number, that means the value you are searching for was not found.

```
int location = Arrays.binarySearch(womenArray, input.toUpperCase());

if (location > 0){    
   System.out.println("found it at " + location + " " + womenArray[location]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... how would I use Arrays.Binary Search for this one? How would I get it to return success?

Comment: so after sorting (Arrays.sort(....)), and after taking input from user, you don't write for loop. You just write int location = Arrays.binarySearch(womenArray, input);

Comment: Oh cool, then I call display womenArray[location] as the result?

Comment: one question, all the strings inside womenArray are capital letters? if yes than you will have to do 1 small change: int location = Arrays.binarySearch(womenArray, input.toUpperCase()); and then yes you do womenArray[location] to print out the woman's name. Remember that, if the location is negative (less than 0), that means the name is not found

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it again. If you have any question let me know

Comment: I've been trying to find String Array examples for my own quicksort and Binary search to make my own algorithm. I cant find any good examples in my textbook either, most of them are INT arrays being sorted and searched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104005/discussion-between-th30d0rab1e-and-faraz-durrani).

Comment: @th30d0rab1e : I can try to write quicksort tomorrow. I looked up online and you were right. They all are written to sort ints. I will try to replicate it for Strings. But no promises :P Right now I am going to sleep. I will have to get some kind of confirmation from you for me to go ahead

Comment: Wont be needed, the assignment is due tonight. But thanks anyways my man.

Comment: @th30d0rab1e r u online?

Comment: No Im watching a movie :D

Comment: lawl i m trying to make quicksort  right now

Comment: quicksort is done xD

Comment: come online on steam plz

Comment: I cant im at a movie theater :/ lol

Comment: okay..... I am posting the solution in the main answer. You can check it and test it and submit it if you want.

Comment: posted quicksort algorithm. Anything else?

Comment: I also wrote binarySearch method. But I wont post it here. I also removed quicksort. Just msg me on steam